# Mysql,how to change "order" of this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I run this query(it's a test db,so don't laugh for name of columns)

```
mysql> select concat (SPACE(temperature),city) as city,temperature from tableexample order by temperature desc;
+------------------------------------------+------------+
| city                                     | temperature|
+------------------------------------------+------------+
|                                Cape Town |         32 |
|                       Paris              |         22 |
|                Rome                      |         15 |
|             New York                     |         12 |
|            London                        |         11 |
+------------------------------------------+------------+
5 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

If I remove SPACE,the output put the number before City

I want an output like this,how to do?

```
+-------------------------+
| city      | temperature |
+-------------------------+
|Cape Town  |         32  |
|Paris      |         22  |
|Rome       |         15  |
|New York   |         12  |
|London     |         11  |
+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Just `select city,temperature from ...` ? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, can't you just 
`select city,temperature from tableexample order by temperature desc;`

Comment: whoops,works fine using just select city,temp..sorry but i'm newbie of mysql

Comment: add as answer,so I can close this question

Comment: I think maybe you can just delete this question. I doubt anyone in the future will wonder why, when they use the `Space()` function, it adds spaces or why, when they use the `Concat()` function, it concatenates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just type:

```
select city,temperature from tableexample order by temperature desc;
```